# Width of container is weird, when using translate

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I want to display a container with some pages floating inside. Some pages on the left should sometimes be hidden. If the width of the pages gets too big, I want to display a scrollbar.

```css
#wrapper{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

#container{
    width: 300px;
    transform: translate(-100px, 0);
}

.page{
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <div class="page">1</div>
        <div class="page">2</div>
        <div class="page">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the width of the container is set to 300px since it contains 3 pages at 100px. Now you can scroll 100px to the right without seeing any content. When I set the width of the container to 200px, it will only show 1 entry.

Can I somehow get rid of the scrollbar, when I do not need it?

Comment: Instead of using `translate`, which does not work with element flow (the elements will still be laid out as if they are not translated), consider using `display: none` on the elements that you want to hide.

Comment: how about the animation before setting it to display: none?